# Echo Mysql Query Result into Box

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have created a row of icon cards and im trying to echo a Different query result into each one, I have tried using ajax and it broke my page

I have tried to placed the PHP code inside where i need the result echoing that also didn't work ( nothing displayed in the box however no errors were displayed in console. so any recommendations would be greatly received

```
      <!-- Icon Cards-->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-3">
          <div class="card text-white bg-primary o-hidden h-100">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="card-body-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-fw fa-clock"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="mr-5"> 
<?php           
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password!", "test");  
$query = "select substring(avg(time_format(time,'%i:%s')),2,5)as time from test.time where date = curdate() ";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  
    echo "['".$row["time"]."']"; 
}  
?> 
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

when i include the current code above it display as the box on the right and the goal is to echo the result to look like the box on the left

[image]

Comment: There is no JS in your code. use correct tags or post relevant code.

Comment: Did you typed your query directly in PHPMyAdmin or MySQLWorkbench to check if it's working as expected?

Comment: Post the ajax as well and maybe we can help you with that as well, and maybe a screenshot of the errors you are getting too. the more info you supply, the better the quality of answers you can receive

Comment: Why did you re-post this question? There were already some hints in the former version

Comment: @NicoHaase for some reason when i went to reply to my former question it had been removed

Comment: And what have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked whether the query returns anything (a result set or an error)?

Comment: so when I run the query individually in workbench it returns a result, if i run the query to return in a table it outputs a result but i i try to echo the query into the icon box nothing displays including not returning any errors, its as if the php itself does not run when i put it between                   <div class="mr-5"> ECHO PHP HERE </div>

Comment: Have you used `View Source` to see if the output is in the HTML?

Comment: having a look in page source it echo's out [''] instead of the query result.

Comment: I have resolved my issue I was using double Quotations instead of single around Time which seems to have been stopping the display of the result